# InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'surroundContents' on 'Range': The Range has partially selected a non-Text node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good day, I am trying to make a reader where user can highlight text by multiple color,I have written code on sandbox link is below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-snowflake-oxko7?file=/src/App.js

everything is working fine but when I am trying change previously highlighted color by selecting selected text I am getting this error .

InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'surroundContents' on 'Range': The Range has partially selected a non-Text node.
[image]

Comment: The relevant code should be in the question as a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538) rather than a sandbox link that can rot over time. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found some Solution and fixed it by it. Link below

changed code from

```
let span = document.createElement("span");

    t = document.all
      ? document.selection.createRange().text
      : document.getSelection();
    setXaxis(e.clientX / 2);
    setYaxis(e.clientY / 2);

    console.log(e.clientX);
    console.log(e.clientY);
    // let text =  document.querySelector(".App").innerText;
    //document.querySelector(".App").html(text.replace(t, spn));
    //document.getElementById('result').innerText = t;
    //alert(t.rangeCount);
    span.style.backgroundColor = color;
    let range = t.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
    range.surroundContents(span);
    t.removeAllRanges();
    t.addRange(range);
```

to

```
 var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
let span = document.createElement("span");

span.style.backgroundColor = color;
span.appendChild(range.extractContents());
range.insertNode(span);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-https-zlfpe?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I am still a bit skeptical as to this is a cross-browser solution; but at least I am getting somewhere now. Thank you mate...

Comment: it works but it like nested element span inside span....

Answer (score 1):

The error is letting you know you're doing something illegal, so you can either try to infer what was the intention and manipulate the `range` manually, which is possible (but not bulletproof) or you can validate the *range* before doing any action:

```js
const isSafeRange = range.startContainer === range.endContainer
```

So if a selection is crossing different nodes, you will detect that and `return`.

BTW, You don't need to clone it in your scenario