# Selection: Check if DOM element can be surrounded?

Tags: javascript, webapi

According to the documentation [surroundContents()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents) surrounds a selected `node`. The docu mentions

> An exception will be thrown, however, if the Range splits a non-Text
> node with only one of its boundary points. That is, unlike the
> alternative above, if there are partially selected nodes, they will
> not be cloned and instead the operation will fail.

What I didn't find is if there is a way to check before if the exception would occur or not. i.e. How to check before executing the operation if the action is possible?

Use case: The user shouldn't be able to perform the action if its not possible.

I know that I can `try catch` the action and prevent that to be happen. But checking before would be great.

Initially I thought about checking if the elements in the `Range.startContainer` and `Range.endContainer` have some block element - but this won't help much. Especially since checking `block` element sounds tricky. `range.cloneRange()` doesn't help much either. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have some example code you're working with? Providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem will probably yield more response.

Comment: Don't know what kind of code to provide. In the initial link a code is provided. Basically it must be some check on the selected nodes - but don't know how to check the selected Range.

Comment: Some duplicates: [How can i get all text nodes inside a dom range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685753/how-can-i-get-all-text-nodes-inside-a-dom-range), [Use javascript to extend a DOM Range to cover partially selected nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477192/use-javascript-to-extend-a-dom-range-to-cover-partially-selected-nodes), [InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'surroundContents' on 'Range': The Range has partially selected a non-Text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67634286/invalidstateerror-failed-to-execute-surroundcontents-on-range-the-range-ha)

Comment: heres a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1t8ve7dn/3/) as a base for testing against.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of documentation: I found the following solution:

```
try {
// check if the browser allows a surround ==> than surround it
    const testRange = selection.getRng().cloneRange();
    testRange.surroundContents(document.createElement('span'));
    // .... perform action 
} catch (error) {
    //surrounding not possbile
}
```

Honestly I dislike the solution since it needs to raise an  error (and then catch it). But if somebody else has a better idea I'm curious.