# DOM Range.cloneRange to test Range.surroundContents for errors

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to clone a range using the Range.cloneRange method without actually updating the DOM.  I want to test if the Range.surroundContents method will throw an error before allowing the user to edit the DOM using the Range.surroundContents method.

```
try {
   const clone = this.EditorRange.cloneRange();
   console.log(clone);
   const element = document.createElement('span');
   clone.surroundContents(element);
   this.ShowText();
} catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
   alert('Invalid surround contents');
   return;
}
```

The code above actually changes the DOM even though I am creating a clone of the initial range.

I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/74719443/654636

Would the following code allow me to determine if Range.surroundContents will throw an error?

```
const isSafeRange = range.startContainer === range.endContainer
```